# Windev constant for test mode

Tags: constants, windev

We have some constants inside our project. One is for the URL of a server. Is it possible to make the constant being different when in test mode?

Something like:

```
IF InTestMode() THEN
    CONSTANT URL = "http://test.com"
ELSE
    CONSTANT URL = "http://prod.com"
END
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant are in fact supposed to be constants.

What you are searching for is a global variable defined at project level.
You can initialize your variable the way you want, using or not your constant with something like that :

```
CONSTANT
    URL_PROD = "http://prod.com"
    URL_TEST = "http://test.com"
END

gsURL is a string = InTestMode() ? URL_TEST ELSE URL_PROD
```